# unhashable type: 'list' when fitting a model - tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to follow a tutorial found at https://github.com/arthurflor23/handwritten-text-recognition/blob/master/src/tutorial.ipynb. When trying to fit the model, I get the following error `unhashable type: 'list'`. I have the following packages installed:

```
tensorboard==2.0.2
tensorflow-estimator==2.0.1
tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0 

CUDA Version 10.0.130
```

When trying to install the shown `tensorflow-gpu==2.1.0-rc0` package, the model starts training, but I can't seem to use my gpu, it can not see it. However, when running the program with the `2.0.2` version, I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` at

```
h = model.fit(x=dtgen.next_train_batch(),
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=dtgen.steps['train'],
    validation_data=dtgen.next_valid_batch(),
    validation_steps=dtgen.steps['valid'],
    callbacks=callbacks,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=1)
```

It takes too long to train the model only using my CPU, so any advice on how to get my gpu to start training would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We also need to check the CuDNN version in order to give you some help. Also, does it work with older versions of TensorFlow. Try with 1.15 or 1.14, both of them support CUDA 10.0

Comment: I use cdnn v7.5.0

Comment: Ok, it seems like downgrading to tensorflow 1.15 fixed the problem, but as soon as it starts training on the first epoch, I get the following error: 
`Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
  [[{{node conv2d/Conv2D}}]]
  [[loss/time_distributed_1_loss/Cast_1/_515]]
`

I only have one version of cudnn installed, what could be the fix of this?

Comment: Maybe install CuDNN 7.6.3. This error means that there is a mismatch between Cuda and Cudnn